# JavaScript Pop up problme before navigating away from a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The code below call the "Click Save!" pop up if there were changes to input fields and someone attempts to navigate away from the page without clicking the submit button to save.

Can someone tell me how to make a small change to this that will call the "Click Save!" pop up for ANY attempt to navigate away from the page even if no changes were made to any of the input fields (but of course still no popup if they click the submit button)?

```
var warnMessage = "Click Save!"; 

$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('input:not(:button,:submit),textarea,select,text').change(function () { 
    window.onbeforeunload = function () { 
        if (warnMessage != null) return warnMessage; }}); 
    $('input:submit').click(function(e) { 
                warnMessage = null; 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Just remove everything except the `onbeforeunload` handler ?

Comment: That works but now it does this for every single page with input or without so i will have to think of something to isolate it only to edit page. Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var warnMessage = false;

window.onbeforeunload = function (event) {
    if (!warnMessage) {
        return;
    }
    else {
        return "You have unsaved changes on this page.  If you wish to save these changes, stay on the current page.";
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input:not(:button,:submit),textarea,select,text').change(function (event) {
        warnMessage = true;
    });

    $('input:submit').click(function () {
        warnMessage = false;
    });
});
```